# Rest Resource URL mapping in workbench

Tags: rest, workbench, restresource

i have written a rest web service class and mapped the resource as '/Accounts/*/contacts'. where * stands for Accountid.

I am trying to do a POST call from workbench and having issue writing server URI.

for example: suppose a resource mapping is "/Accounts/*", it corresponding URI mapping for doing POST call through workbench will be : 
/services/apexrest/Accounts/.

Similarly, Please suggest how to write URI in workbench for resource mapping '/Accounts/*/contacts'.  Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `*` is a wildcard. It just allows Salesforce to map the URL to your class when a parameter is included. To use your example,

`/Accounts/*`

can map the URL

`/services/apexrest/Accounts/PARAMETER`

where your class can parse and utilize the parameter value - an Account Id or External Id, for example.

Interstitial wildcards do the same thing.

`/Accounts/*/Contacts`

would map the URL

`/services/apexrest/Accounts/PARAMETER/Contacts`

to, for example, return data about the Contacts associated with the Account identified by the value `PARAMETER`.

For more, see [`RestResource` Annotation](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_classes_annotation_rest_resource.htm):

> URL path mappings are as follows:
>
> The path must begin with a '/' 
> If an '*' appears, it must be preceded by '/' and followed by '/', unless the '*' is the last character, in which case it need not be followed by '/'

Salesforce does not parse the URL into parameters for your class; you're responsible for inspecting the incoming request and parsing and validating any parameters you expect. If your web service does not accept any parameters, I don't see any reason why you'd use a wildcard in your URL mapping.